# JSON.NET Production Issue

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net

I have an ASPNET Core project that is running a set of RESTful services using C# and Newtonsoft.JSON 11.0.2 which I incorporated using NuGet.  When I run everything locally using Visual Studio 2017 and IIS Express, things work fine and my JSON Deserializer efforts work with no issue.

When I publish the solution in a Web Deploy package and then install that application in IIS 10 on a Windows Server 2016 instance in AWS, the deserializer fails.  The error is:

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0

It does not matter if I publish in Debug or Release mode.

I ran Postman calls and the JSON being returned is both validate and produces the correct objects.  I did see that, in the Solution Explorer, the version is 11.0.2 but in the assets JSON file, the version is pointed to 10.0.1.  The .CS project file, when viewed in a text editor outside of Visual Studio, does show 11.0.2.

When I look in the deployed application's folder on the server, I do not see any NewtonSoft DLLs but I do see other NuGet-obtained DLLs.  This might not be an issue given how JSON.NET deploys but I thought it was worth mentioning.

I then included a logger and sent the incoming JSON to a file and, again, it all validated as expected.

I have tried everything, ensured CORS is properly implemented both in the application and in IIS.  I am at a complete loss as to how to proceed.

Can somebody please help?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the JSON response returned from API? Also, share code for deserializing json

Comment: You don't have to reference JSON.NET explicitly, as its implcitly already referenced by ASP.NET Core. Maybe a version conflict, or the deployment strips off the JSON.NET library because its already in the runtime. Maybe old/outdated runtime on your server? Did you install the latest sdk or runtime on the server?

Comment: If the first character encountered when parsing is `<`, you can be sure that is not JSON.  Something is probably sending XML or HTML to your code in the deployed environment.  I would look at that angle.  This doesn't seem like a version conflict to me, otherwise you would be getting a much different error about not being able to load the file or assembly.  I think this is solely a data problem.

Comment: @Brian Rogers - Thank you SO MUCH for this last comment.  I ended up opening Production to my development machine and then running Wireshark to see the communications.  Turns out that IIS had "GEWT" instead of "GET" in the allowed methods web.config for the host website and I was getting rejections in the cloud instead of the JSON.  Every test I ran which generated output was LocalHost but, of course, none of the real production work used anything local.  Once I fixed that error, everything worked great!

Comment: That's great!  I'm glad you found the issue and it turned out to be something simple.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved by this code in web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
        <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes browse old question that has no/accepted answers and check if they are still in need of some help, or if something can be done to close the cold case.

This post has already been solved, but the cause and the solution were left only in the comments.

> If the first character encountered when parsing is <, you can be sure
> that is not JSON. Something is probably sending XML or HTML to your
> code in the deployed environment. I would look at that angle. This
> doesn't seem like a version conflict to me, otherwise you would be
> getting a much different error about not being able to load the file
> or assembly. I think this is solely a data problem.
> Brian Rogers

> @Brian Rogers - Thank you SO MUCH for this last comment. I ended up
> opening Production to my development machine and then running
> Wireshark to see the communications. Turns out that IIS had "GEWT"
> instead of "GET" in the allowed methods web.config for the host
> website and I was getting rejections in the cloud instead of the JSON.
> Every test I ran which generated output was LocalHost but, of course,
> none of the real production work used anything local. Once I fixed
> that error, everything worked great!
> Ken Tola

@ken-tola, can you please self-answer the question and then accept it to close the case.